Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
I came across this problem after deploying my Nest.js backend on vercel + firebase db, can it be connected with ssl or something else and how to fix it?
I tried to config ssl in my firebase service, but cauthgh another problem
